# Format output of Fortran program

Tags: formatting, fortran, output, gfortran

I inherited some code, for a Chemistry simulation. I have the code working, with the exception that the output functions WRITE and FORMAT are giving me a hard time. I was reading the gfortran online manual, and saw that gfortran does not support FORMAT, stating that it is non-standard, and not as configurable as WRITE. That's fine, I would happily replace it, but I am having trouble figuring out how to format FORTRAN output.

What I want, is to have text, preceding a variable. such as:
ZETA = 12.34
where ZETA is text, and 12.34 is the content of some variable. 
or in C++, `cout << "ZETA = " << ZETA ;`

I've been reading old web pages, and trying a variety of things, but I'm not getting anywhere. 
Consider this sample code:

```
      PROGRAM MAIN
      REAL ZETA1, ZETA2
      ZETA1 = 2.173171
      ZETA2 = 1.18530
      WRITE(*,"(A6)" Zeta1:,ZETA1, "(2F7.4)")
C 10   FORMAT *( ZETA 1, ZETA 2*,2F7.4)
      END
```

the C commented line, is an original formating line, which throws an error. 
How could the output be formated to display

ZETA1 2.1731

ZETA2 1.1853

Any help, or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: actually, your `c++` does not specify a format, arguably the equivalent fortran is a simple list directed write, `write(*,*)'ZETA1 ',zeta`

Comment: Not here to argue, just here to solve problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some examples:

```
   PROGRAM MAIN
       REAL ZETA1, ZETA2
       ZETA1 = 2.173171
       ZETA2 = 1.18530
       write (*, '( "Zeta1:", F7.4 / "Zeta2:", F7.4 )' )  ZETA1, ZETA2
       write (*, '( 2 (A, F7.4 / ) )' )  "Zeta1", ZETA1,"Zeta2", ZETA2
       write (*, 1010) ZETA1, ZETA2
       1010 format ( "Zeta1=", F7.4 / "Zeta2=", F7.4 )
    END program main
```

Comment: Thank you, for ending my torment. I applied similar changes, to the rest of the source, and I am now done! woot! I extend my sincere appreciation!